# tracing pthreads in linux?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading

I did not find any tool created for tracing pthread's threads in linux process. I want something like strace/ltrace, is there something to view calls in real-time? 
Thank you

Answer (score 19, accepted):

strace works for threads as well. Use `strace -f` to strace all threads.

To strace only a particular thread, you first have to find its tid (thread id). 
Threads have thread id's that's really a pid (process id)

Once you know the pid of the thread, use `strace -p the_pid` to strace that thread.

The pids of all the threads in a process can be found in `/proc/<pid>/task/` , or the current thread id can be learned with the `gettid()` C call.

Comment: wow thank you very much, i see strace's help hundred times but did not think that 'follow forks' will show threads

Comment: This does not work (for me, anyway).  To be more specific, I'm using strace -f -p <pid> to attach the the thread I want to watch.  Whenever it accepts a new socket connection it creates a pthread to handle it, but strace doesn't follow the pthread_create call into the new thread at all.

Answer (score 3):

actually strace is not as good as perf .

use perf tool , you can get more information.

for example, if some of your threads hangs , and you want to find out what functions calls that hangs, 
use strace -p pid-id returns limited information, but perf top , or perf -t tid returns more